# Java: How to run a Java process in a specific directory?

Tags: java, php, bash

When I run a jar file, say in `/home/jars` like such `java -jar /home/jars/jarfile.jar`, it seems to run in whatever directory I'm in.

How do I make it so `java -jar /home/jars/jarfile.jar` runs with `/home/jars` as the current working directory??

Comment: A better question is 'why does the code need to know the user.dir?'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer:

```
( cd /home/jars; java -jar /home/jars/jarfile.jar )
```

[See also this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java).

The analogy for most languages supporting an `exec` call, is the variant of `exec` that lets you specify a working directory.

[See this for simple PHP solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679045/php-exec-command-how-to-specify-working-directory).

Comment: Read the link provided in answer.  The bottom line portable solution is that the JVM must be launched into the desired directory.  The link does provide other alternatives.