# php exec command does not work after i used putenv?

Tags: php, laravel, shell, cmd, exec

I want to run command via php, what I've tried

```
<?php
$out=exec("pwd")
echo $out
?>
```

**Output:**
c//xampp/htdocscommands

Problem arised in this case

```
<?php
putenv('PATH=C:\xampp\htdocs\command\execute ');
$out=exec('pwd');
echo $out;
?>
```

**Output:**
operable program or batch file.

Then I try to run even simple command exe("pwd"), I'm getting this error

```
operable program or batch file.
```

What I'm trying exactly is

1. I need to run command via php exec or other syntex too
2. I need to set the path right way

e.g.: exec("cd path  some_command")

Comment: The `pwd` is a program inside your `C:\xampp\htdocs\command\execute` directory or is the Linux pwd command? And Whey you put the directory in env?

Comment: i accidently used because of i am tryng to change my path upto cmd directory folder after i used putenv stopped all command also like ipconfig too so why i post this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679045/php-exec-command-how-to-specify-working-directory
Does this answer help you?

Comment: Now directory working but i still get same above mentioned error